# Is the threshold frequency for the photoelectric effect related to the mass of the electron?

Tags: electrons, photoelectric-effect

I'm going to prefix this by saying that (a) physics is not my strong point and (b) I'm aware this is probably a coincidence.

I learnt that the threshold frequency for the photoelectric effect is $\approx 10.4 \times 10^{14} \text{ Hz}$. I noticed that the square of the reciprocal of this is $\approx 9.24556 \times 10^{-31} \text{ s}^2$, and the mass of an electron is $\approx 9.10939 \times 10^{-31} \text{ kg}$.

If, instead of $\approx 10.4 \times 10^{14} \text{ Hz}$, the threshold frequency was $\approx 10.477444 \times 10^{14} \text{ Hz}$ (I'm not saying that it is, in fact I don't know what it is, and when trying to find a more exact value I've found that apparently it depends on the material, and obviously this would be $\approx 10.5 \times 10^{14} \text{ Hz}$ anyway), then the square of the reciprocal would be $\approx 9.10939 \times 10^{-31} \text{ s}^2$.

I realise that the units are different, but as an incredibly amateur amateur I'm wondering if this is a thing or not? Like, are the two quantities related? I mean, inverse squares appear quite regularly in physics, right?

Comment: No correlation, just bogus numerology. Different units would yield different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is most certainly no correlation and what you have found is coincidental.

The threshold frequency is different for different metals and so your value of $\nu_0$ is for some specific metal (I assume that if there was some physical correlation, using your method, you'd get the electron mass $m_e$ possibly for any value of $\nu_0$ which makes no sense).

As you have stated, the units are different. Mass has units $kg$ and not $s^2$. The two quantities are physically distinct.